# How do you create a scrolling area on a webpage that tracks the browser window's height?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I'm wondering specifically how to get the kind of scrolling div used by the SpineJS documentation:

http://spinejs.com/docs/ajax

You'll see that if you resize the window, the scrolling div on the right side (as well as the left) adjusts its height to track the window's height.

What are the key css and js elements of this trick?

Answer (score 1):

The solution used on the website that you've mentioned is only CSS.

**The key elements are:**

CSS [position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

CSS [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)

CSS [height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)

CSS [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

See this [working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/35AaC/) and analyze the CSS used to see how it is done! Also, read the links above to know more about those CSS properties and learn to combine them!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are just using the css property `overflow: auto` on the elements.  That will add scrollbars if the child content exceeds the parent boundaries.

And the element itself is absolutely positioned with top, bottom and right set to 0px;